# Where can I find the source code of Gnome-Shell 3.10 Status Indicator/Bar?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnome-shell

In Gnome Shell 3.10 indicators (sound, network,..) were merged in single status bar. I read that applications need to make gnome shell extensions to show an icon there. So I searched for default indicators in `gnome-shell-extensions`, but negative results.

Where can I find the code of default indicators in Gnome source git repository? and In which package it has been built in Debian or Ubuntu repository?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all gnome projects here https://git.gnome.org/browse/.

And this is the documentation to develop https://developer.gnome.org/guides.

The man behind the design of all that is [William Jon McCann](https://wiki.gnome.org/WilliamJonMcCann) you can try to talk to him.